# Java generic type T toString()

Tags: java, generics

I have a method, which I cannot change, that takes a `T[]` array.

I need to "`toString()`" element `[i]` of array, not knowing the type of `T` in advance.

For all objects, I could call `toString()` but `T[]` could be an array of primitives and this does not make sense:

```
int i = 0;
i.toString(); // nonsense
```

What can I do?

Comment: No, `T[]` cannot be an array of primitives.

Comment: Well, occasionally I do get boxed primitives, such as Integer, Long, etc.. but I suppose I can just call .toString on them? Then the problem really does not exist and the question is madly stupid. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In response to:

> T[] could be an array of primitives and this does not make sense

Generic types cannot be primitives, which guarantees that the array will always be an array of objects.  Since every object extends `Object` it will have a `toString` method.

Answer (score 2):

A generic type can't be a primitive. The problem doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Generics can't be used with primitive types. Therefore, `T[]` cannot be an array of primitives. Consequently, you can always call `arr[i].toString()` when `arr` is of type `T[]`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will allow the `.toString()` call, which should be a good clue to you that it will actually work. Only when the Java compiler **doesn't** allow you something is it time to think about how to do it anyway. That's the order of things in Java.